# Developing with a local non-artifactory module

Tags: android, gradle, artifactory

I have a large project with several modules and need to do some development with a change on one of the modules from Artifactory, but without pushing my changes to that module back to Artifactory, so the top level project leverages the local changes to the module from Artifactory.

Unfortunately, every time I build the Android project with Gradle, the top level project uses the Artifactory module, not my local changes.

How can I get this to work?  I have been unable to find how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you'll use gradle's new [dependency substitution rules](https://docs.gradle.org/2.5/release-notes#dependency-substitution-rules) feature available since gradle 2.5.

**build.gradle**

```
resolutionStrategy {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module("org.foo:utility") with project(":utility")
    }
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include 'utility'
project(':utility').projectDir = new File('c:/path/to/utility')
```

Another option is [prezi pride](https://github.com/prezi/pride)

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608433/gradle-buildship-switch-dependency-between-jar-and-projects/32609738) and [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/remap-jars-not-working-with-local-maven-repo-in-eclipse/10987/2)